# Implement parcelable interface using Gson

Tags: android, gson, parcelable

I'm trying to implement the parcelable interface using Gson. The idea is to create a json string (using gson) and write it to the parcel object.

Could it be a correct way to implement the interface?

The only problem I've encountered is when I deserialize the object. Actually, I use gson to recreate the object.

```
private MyClass(Parcel in) {
    String json = in.readString();
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    gson.fromJson(json, getClass());
}
```

The problem is that the `fromJson` function returns an object that is the object the constructor should create.
The last line of code should be something like

```
this=gson.fromJson(json, getClass());
```

So, if this is a correct way to implement `Parcelable`, how could I solve this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should read more carefully the [Parcelable javadoc](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcelable.html). It contains everything you need.

As quoted in the docs :

> Interface for classes whose instances can be written to and restored
>   from a Parcel. Classes implementing the Parcelable interface must also
>   have a static field called CREATOR, which is an object implementing
>   the Parcelable.Creator interface.

So you should have the `writeToParcel` method declared and also use a creator that will produce instances of your class from a Parcel.

The private constructor is an additional helper that you can use to set the value of the fields of an object given a parcel, but not the object itself. In Java, `this` is a right value, and can't be assigned.

BTW, the goal of parcelisation is to be provide a short term fast serialization process. You should, generally speaking, use a fast and compact data format when you use parcelisation. JSON is not a candidate of choice, but it will work.

Comment: Ok thanks. I already know how to implement Parcelable. I was just wondering if it is good to implement it using json notation, just because it would be faster to implement with gson.

Comment: Why is "JSON not a candidate of choice"? You say it should be fast and compact, and JSON is compact, and should be more than fast enough under normal circumstances. I like to use Json for this.

Comment: @CorayThan, binary formats compress more and should be faster to compress/decompress usually than having to parse strings.